# How work KeepAlive in THttpClient?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

If i do the scenario below :

```
MyHttpClient := ThttpClient.create;
MyHttpClient.Get('https://www.siteA.com');
MyHttpClient.Get('https://www.siteB.com');
MyHttpClient.Get('https://www.siteA.com');
```

Does the http connection (and the https handshaking) will be made for each request to https://www.siteA.com or just for the first request and reused in the second? this for android / ios and windows

And in such scenario :

```
MyHttpClient1 := ThttpClient.create;
MyHttpClient1.Get('https://www.siteA.com');
MyHttpClient1.disposeOf;


MyHttpClient2 := ThttpClient.create;
MyHttpClient2.Get('https://www.siteA.com');
MyHttpClient2.disposeOf;
```

same as previous, Does the http connection (and the https handshaking) will be made for each request or just for the first one and reused by the second ?

How can i test this behavior under android / ios ?

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, your are sending requests to different hostnames, so regardless of whether the `THTTPClient` object is reused or not, separate TCP connections and HTTPS handshakes *must* be used for each request, even if the hostnames resolve to the same IP address.  Once a TCP connection has completed a handshake, a new handshake for a different hostname cannot be sent over the existing TCP connection. So `THTTPClient` must drop the connection and create a new one on the 2nd and 3rd requests. KeepAlive only works for sequential requests to the same hostname.

In the second example, you are using separate `THTTPClient` objects, so the TCP connection will be dropped and reconnected even though the requests are to the same hostname.  `THTTPClient` does not cache TCP connections between objects.

Comment: thanks remy, but is it possible to test this (and how)? as THTTPClient use internally the os api, i hope the op api keep the socket open to handle such behavior of programmers.

Comment: @loki a network packet sniffer can verify this behavior for you

Comment: maybe i can build fastly myself an httpserver with your indy component to see it?